# Infer column with as 'string' in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I infer a column designated with '`as`' like:

```
select 'foo' as 'bar'
where 'bar' = 'foo'
order by 'bar'
```

I can see, that '`order by`' clause seems to accept '`bar`'.
The '`where`' clause, simply does a `string-compare`, and returns false.
I'd skip escaping the quotes with double-quotes, as it's a `string-compare` anyways. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Note that `order by 'bar'` means "order by the *literal string* `'bar'` **not** "order by the column `[bar]`", and `where 'bar' = 'foo'` means "when the literal string `'bar'` has the value of the literal string `'foo'`" (which will never be true). For columns you need to either no quote them (`bar`), or quote them in brackets (`[bar]`) or double quotes (`"bar"`). Anything inside a single quote (`'`) is treated as a literal string and not a columns name. *(`as 'bar'` is not referencing a column, it is assigning an alias to an expression, so is different.)*

Comment: I'd take this one as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The SQL clause  (select ,  from , where  ,, order by ) are evaluated  in a specific sequence ..  the order  by clause is evaluated  after the select clause so the order by clause know the presence of the alias  .. the where clause is evaluated  before the select clause and for this you have  the error  ..  for the where clasue you mus repeat the same column name in select

in you case using the single quote you are just comparing string not column   if you need  the correct approach you  should use

```
select 'foo' as bar
from dual
where 'foo' = 'foo'
order by bar
```

Comment: To add to this: [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

Comment: Okay, I guess same situation goes here as well: select 'foo' as 'bar'
having 'bar' in
(
 'foo'
)
order by 'bar'

Comment: having clause is not as where clause   having clause  is evalueted  on result  of the query .. so  evaluated  after the select  clause .. (before order by)

Comment: Okay, I understood. These are basics only. I shall read from the link above.

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done, since the alias foo -> bar is only available outside the select. The where-clause is evaluated before the select-part.

```
select foo, bar
from
(
 select foo, foo as bar
 from dual
) as i
where bar = foo
order by bar
```

Comment: I tried this query, with some modifications: furthest I could reach was: select 'bar' from 
(
  select 'foo' as 'bar'
) x

Comment: Strange, it worked for me, in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/08d75c/3

Comment: Same but with brackets, to clarify object names: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/08d75c/4

Answer (score 1):

This would work if your original query was a subquery and not as it is. So something like -

```
select bar from 
(
  select 'foo' as 'bar'
  from dual
) where 'bar' = 'foo'
  order by 'bar'
```